# How to write a function that outputs a two-column table

Tags: python

I need help with creating a table. The question is asking me to write a function that outputs a two column table of kilogram weights and their pound equivalents for kilogram values `0`, `10`, `20` ..., `100`.

So far I have:

```
kilos = eval(input("Enter a weight in kilograms: ")) 
pounds = 2.2 * kilos 
print("The weight in pounds is", pounds)
```

but I have no idea how to construct this as a table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you. We're here to help you with problems you've encountered!

Comment: What did you try? You probably want to loop over every row, while displaying the 2 elements.

Comment: sorry ive got something like 
'kilos = eval(input("Enter a weight in kilograms: "))'
'pounds = 2.2 * kilos'
'print("The weight in pounds is", pounds)'

but I have no idea how to construct this as a table. As i said, any help is appreciated. @Blckknght

Comment: Ulgh - please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/3001761. What do you mean *"construct this as a table"*? On a web page, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12453799/3001761)? In a database? In the interpreter?

Comment: Yes, similar to that table. I just need to show it in an IDE @jonrsharpe, but thank you anyways. Someone gave me a pretty useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By table I assume that you are trying to print the output on console.

```
mult_factor = 2.20462 
print ('Kilogram', 'Pound')
for i in range (0, 100, 10):
    print (i , i * mult_factor)
```

Comment: thats awesome of you and it makes sense to me. Thank you